# check bound datatable for null value vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, null

I am currently working in vb.net windows form applications with an sql back end. I have two datatables that are bound to two independent sql statements and both return two very simple datatables. I just need to check to see if there is a null value in either of the two tables, independently. The first query returns a single value, literally a single cell. I have always used the following code in a dgv to check for null

```
Dim Check As Integer = dt.Rows(1).cells(1).value
```

However this is not working here, it seems to be because the data type is an integer. Usually with a DGV I am doing a click event and am pulling from a dgv an end user can see.

The second sql query is just 2 cells. As in it has 2 rows and one column and I need to check both cells to make sure neither of them are null.

I have been looking around online but I cant find anything that seems to work for me.

------------------------update----------------------------

```
 Public Shared Function ToInt32(Value As Object) As Integer
    If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
        Return 0
    Else
        Return Convert.ToInt32(Value)
    End If
End Function



  Dim ncheck As Integer
  ncheck = SafeConvert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(1)(1))
```

How would i use this ncheck in a if statement to run an exit sub and a message box? It seems to me if ncheck is not an integer it is just going to crash on me.

Comment: if `cells(1)` has no data defined, it will return DBNull.  Test for that

Comment: *usually* you check for DBNull in order to avoid an error and if it is not DBNull then assign the value to a variable.  SafeConvert does both for you although it uses a default value for when it *is* DBNull.  If you want to specifically respond to DBNull, you will have to test it.  Multiple versions exist for the various datatypes you might need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `DbNull.Value`:

```
   If Not DbNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows(1).Item(1).value) Then 
      ' do something
   Else 
      ' do something else 
   End If
```

or use

```
If dt.Rows(1).Item(1).value=DbNull.Value
```

Comment: I am getting an error on this code for the section (dt.rows(1).cells(1)) that "cells is not a member of system.data.datarow."

Comment: It is still giving me the error message on the "cells" portion.

Comment: what about `If dt.Rows(1).cells(1).value=DbNull.Value`?

Comment: so, sorry for couldn't help you, I don't know exactly what and how is your code, I hope you'll get it fixed soon. good luck.

Comment: try using Item instead of Cell - `If dt.Rows(1).Item(1).value=DbNull.Value`

Comment: @JStevens, at the beginning I told myself to write Item instead of cells but then I told maybe it's a customized form and works for OP no matter lets write cells!, however thanks I'll edit again.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a set of Safe Conversion methods you can use either as shared methods or maybe convert them to extensions:

```vb
Class SafeConvert   
    Public Shared Function ToInt32(Value As Object) As Integer
        If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Convert.ToInt32(Value)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ToInt64(Value As Object) As Int64
        If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Convert.ToInt64(Value)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Function ToDecimal(Value As Object) As Decimal
        If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
            Return 0
        Else
            Return Convert.ToDecimal(Value)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Shared Shadows Function ToString(Value As Object) As String
        If DBNull.Value.Equals(Value) Then
            Return String.Empty
        Else
            Return Convert.ToString(Value)
        End If
    End Function

End Class
```

Example:

```vb
Dim nCheck As Integer
nCheck = SafeConvert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(1)(1))
' or
nCheck = SafeConvert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(0).Item(1))
```

Of course, the row has to be valid and have a cell at that index, this is just testing for `DBNull`, not a `NullReference`.

Comment: I like this system, I am about to update my code. So if i wanted to stop the code if ncheck did bring back a null value would i do that with an if statement saying if ncheck was not an integer or something like that?

Comment: Ohhh wait i see, its just going to give me the number 0 if its anything other than an integer so i can just see if its 0 or not.

Comment: If you want to **test** it, use `IsDbNull` or `DBNull.Value.Equals`.  These are for converting to some safe value.  You could change it to return a passed default value, or your `Check` var could be defined as `Nullable(of Int32)` and return a null

Comment: Thanks for the sheet, I am going to figure out how to use that and have it in my programs in the future. It is very helpful.