# Exception "Operator '>' is not defined for the 'DBNull' and type integer"

Tags: vb.net, dbnull

How to handle this exception

> Operator '>' is not defined for the 'DBNull' and type integer.

I am handling `DBNull` like this in my code.

```
rsGrp.Rows(i).Item("Dr") = IIf(
    rsTemp.Rows(0).Item("Debit") Is Nothing Or 
    rsTemp.Rows(0).Item("Debit") Is DBNull.Value, 
        0, 
        rsTemp.Rows(0).Item("Debit"))
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29611932/1070452

Answer (score 1):

Try using `.ToString = ""`  to check for DBNull

```
rsGrp.Rows(i).Item("Dr") = IIf(rsTemp.Rows(0).Item("Debit").ToString= "", 0, rsTemp.Rows(0).Item("Debit"))
```

hope it Works

Comment: It is not working ,Similer error were shown ,Operator '>' is not defined for the 'DBNull' and type integer @ akhil kumar

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a `DbNull`-check before you read the value. Something like

```
If Not IsDbNull(r("debit")) Then

    //code
End If
```