# SqlDataReader stopped when the value in database is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I'm new to vb and I'm creating a project where I can edit a account so far I'm having trouble with it. The `.read` function stopped when the value in my database is NULL

```
ElseIf ButtonChoice = 2 Then
            txtIDnumber.Text = val
            Dim EditFamilyProfile As New SqlCommand("Select * From [186].[dbo].[familyInfo] WHERE pFnumber = @pFnumber", Connection)
            EditFamilyProfile.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            EditFamilyProfile.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pFnumber", txtIDnumber.Text)
            Dim drEdit As SqlDataReader
            drEdit = EditFamilyProfile.ExecuteReader
            With drEdit
                .Read()
                txtLastName.Text = .Item(1)
                txtFirstName.Text = .Item(2)
                txtMiddleName.Text = .Item(3)
                txtExt.Text = .Item(4)
                txtAddress.Text = .Item(5)
                cmbGender.Text = .Item(6)
.close()
            End With
        End If
```

It stopped in `txteExt.text` because it has a NULL value. There is no error shown. Its just go to the code:

```
  ButtonChoice = 2
        Dim obb As New frm_FamilyReg
        obb.val = Me.txtIDnumber.Text()
        obb.Show()
        Me.Close()
```

Comment: try parsing the value from datareader to string

Comment: possible duplicate of [check bound datatable for null value vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29611679/check-bound-datatable-for-null-value-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if you have a dbNUll value using `IsDBNull()` function and if has, skip it.

```
if not IsDBNull(txtLastName.Text = .Item(1)) then
   txtLastName.Text = .Item(1)
End If
```

Comment: If you want to use SqlDataReader then you have to do it. Because we can't run a loop through SqlDataReader. Loops can be applied to DataTables and that will be different method.

Comment: even the bit. Damn. But Im confused coz I did it with my checkstate on my other project and it work perfectly.

Comment: Mark it answered and close the question if you got the answer.

Comment: Man im sorry. But it still doesnt work when I tried it

Comment: That's strange. What are the results ? Is there any specific error ?