# Vb.net - Read a currency value in a sql query

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

What I am doing here is, selecting a record from a database in a listview, and I am inserting a currency value into a textbox. I have a currency column named "RebateValue" in my access database. My problem is being able to assign a integer value with the amount inside 'RebateValue'.
Error Message: 'Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

```
    Dim query As String = "select ID,RebateValue from RebateInfoStorage where ID=@ID"
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(query, RebateDirectory.CouponConnection)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = RebateSelectedID
        Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        ReceivedRebates.RecordsReceived.Items.Clear()
        Dim Amount As Integer
        While reader.Read
            'This is where I get the error
            Amount = reader.GetValue(1)
            UpdateCredentials.TextBox2.Text = FormatCurrency(Amount, -1, TriState.True)
        End While
        reader.Close()
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29611932/1070452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in the database is null apparently.  You need to put in code to check and handle that.  You can check that using this syntax:

```
if reader.IsDBNull(1) Then
  'put in code to handle appropriately
Else
  Amount = reader.GetValue(1)
```

Comment: Try declaring Amount as a Decimal instead of an Integer.  You could also use GetDecimal instead of GetValue