# How To Show A Null Value From Database In TextBox In VB.NET

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I want to bring records stored in my SQL server DB to my form in VB.NET, I did below coding and it works fine but is there any other better way to handle NULL value from DB column that is going to be displayed in the textbox?

```
If DBNull.Value.Equals(dt.Rows(0).Item("fine_amt")) Then
                txtFine_amt.Text = ""
            Else
                txtFine_amt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("fine_amt")
            End If
```

If we don't handle Null value then it is going to throw an error: Conversion from type 'DBNull' to type 'String' is not valid

Comment: "Better" in what way?  extract the value to a variable? Use a conditional operator?

Comment: [See also this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29611932/1070452)

Comment: @Plutonix thanks just checked it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm reading your question right, it sounds like you could just do this:

```
txtFine_amt.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("fine_amt").ToString()
```

For null values, `ToString()` will always just return an empty string.

Comment: thank you this seems better and short way to achieve same thing :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's really "better" but you could extract the value to a variable and use a conditional operator:

```
Dim value As Object = dt.Rows(0).Item("fine_amt")
txtFine_amt.Text = If(DBNull.Value.Equals(value), "", value)
```

Comment: Thank you! looks fine. I was curious that how many ways are available to handle Null value coming from DB into VB form

Comment: @Hazmat Well, you're handling the null value the exact same way - it just reorganizes the code a little to make it more _compact_.  Use whatever methods you can to get it to _work_, then focus on making it _better_.  Shorter code is not always better code.

Comment: Thank you Stanley for the advice